# Replacing the 2nd occurence of a set of characters with a corresponding set of characters in python

Tags: python

Aim of program: To replace
a/A with 4,
e/E with 3,
i/I with !,
o with ooo,
O with 000,
such that on every 2nd occurrence of each character the replacement is made

"aAa eEe iIi oOo uUu" should result in the program printing "a4a e3e i!i o000o u|_|u"

If the 2nd o is capital, it is replaced with 000. If the 2nd o is lowercase, it is replaced with ooo.

```
def vowel_swapper(string, a, b):
   return string.replace(a, b, 2).replace(b, a, 1)

string = input("Enter:")
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
replacement = ['4', '3', '!', 'ooo', '|_|', '4', '3', '!', '000', '|_|']

for i in range(9):
   newstring = vowel_swapper(string, vowels[i], replacement[i])
   string = newstring

print(newstring)
```

This just outputs
aAa eEe iIi oOo uUu --> aA4 eE3 iI! oOooo uU|_|

as it doesn't avoid the upper/lower case problem. Please could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def vovel_swapper(string: str):
    occurences = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    result = ""
    for char in string:
        if char.upper() == 'A':
            occurences[0] += 1
            if occurences[0] == 2:
                result += '4'
                occurences[0] = 0
            else:
                result += char
        elif char.upper() == 'E':
            occurences[1] += 1
            if occurences[1] == 2:
                result += '3'
                occurences[1] = 0
            else:
                result += char
        elif char.upper() == 'I':
            occurences[2] += 1
            if occurences[2] == 2:
                result += '!'
                occurences[2] = 0
            else:
                result += char
        elif char.upper() == 'O':
            occurences[3] += 1
            if occurences[3] == 2:
                result += char * 3
                occurences[3] = 0
            else:
                result += char
        else:
            result += char
     return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def vowel_swapper(str):
    replacements = {
        'A': '4',   'a': '4',
        'E': '3',   'e': '3',
        'I': '!',   'i': '!',
        'O': '000', 'o': 'ooo',
        'U': '_',   'u': '_'
    }
    counts = {k.upper(): 0 for k in replacements.keys()}
    result = ''
    for ch in str:
        up = ch.upper()
        if up in counts:
            counts[up] += 1
            if counts[up] == 2:
                counts[up] = 0
                ch = replacements[ch]
        result += ch
    return result


some_string = input('Enter:')
print(vowel_swapper(some_string))
```

On your example:

```
Enter:aAa eEe iIi oOo uUu
a4a e3e i!i o000o u_u
```

Case-swapped:

```
Enter:AaA EeE IiI OoO UuU
A4A E3E I!I OoooO U_U
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I was trying to do this using a dictionary but couldn't figure out how to link it to the recurrence but this makes a lot of sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing something like this:

## Code

```py
replacement = {"a":"4",
               "e":"3",
               "i":"!",
               "o":"ooo",
               "u":"|_|",
               "A":"4",
               "E":"3",
               "I":"!",
               'O': '000',
               'U':"|_|"
}

string = list(input("Enter:"))
 
f = [string[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]

rnt = []
for j in f:
  h = [d.lower() for d in j]
  if h.count(h[0]) == len(h):
    j[1] = replacement[j[1]]
  rnt.append("".join(j))
  
print("Output: ","".join(rnt))
```

---

## Output

```py
Enter:aAaeEeiIioOouUu
Output: a4ae3ei!io000ou|_|u
```

---

## Explanation

*I "chunked" the input list by 3 and per n in that chunked list. I match if all the items are equal (same letter) if they are then it'll replace it by comparing it with the `replacement` dictionary*

---